# Need to route instance calls inside a python class

Tags: python, class, instance

The problem is a need to take the arguments into account before choosing the responder. Here is my attempt so far.

```
from responders import A, B, C

class RandomResponder(object)
    def init(self, *args, *kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        # pick a responder based on the args the function was called with
        # I don't know how to do this part
        # for sake of argument lets the args a function was called with lead me to pick responder A
        r = A
        responder = r(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        return responder.__getattr__(name)
```

The desired effect would be:

```
r = RandomResponder()
r.doSomething(1)
#returns A.doSomething()
r.doSomething(2)
#returns B.doSomething()
r.doSomething(3)
#return C.doSomething()
r.doSomethingElse(1)
#returns A.doSomethingElse()
r.doSomethingElse(2)
#returns B.doSomethingElse()
r.doSomethingElse(3)
#returns C.doSomethingElse()
```

I will not know ahead of time all the functions contained with the responders A, B, and C.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do, can you give more information? (I'd also clarify the title)

Comment: Please update your question with additional facts; commenting on an answer isn't as helpful as fixing your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class RandomResponder(object):
    choices = [A, B, C]

    @classmethod
    def which(cls):
        return random.choice(cls.choices)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.which(), attr)
```

which() randomly selects an option from the choices, and which **getattr** uses to get the attribute.

EDIT: it actually looks like you want something more like this.

```
class RandomResponder(object):
    choices = [A, B, C]

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        # we define a function that actually gets called
        # which takes up the first positional argument,
        # the rest are left to args and kwargs
        def doCall(which, *args, **kwargs):
            # get the attribute of the appropriate one, call with passed args
            return getattr(self.choices[which], attr)(*args, **kwargs)
        return doCall
```

This could be written using lambda, but I'll just leave it like this so it's clearer.

Comment: Very clever by you and dF, I never thought to return a function that contains the logic.

Answer (score 3):

When you do this

```
r.doSomething(1)
```

what happens is, in order:

- `r.__getattr__` is called, and returns an object
- this object is called with an argument "1"

At the time when `__getattr__` is called, you have no way of knowing what arguments the object you return is *going* to get called with, or even if it's going to be called at all...

So, to get the behavior that you want, `__getattr__` has to return a callable object that makes the decision itself based on the arguments *it's* called with. For example

```
from responders import A, B, C

class RandomResponder(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def func(*args, **kwds):
            resp = { 1:A, 2:B, 3:C }[args[0]]    # Decide which responder to use (example)
            return getattr(resp, name)()         # Call the function on the responder
        return func
```

Comment: Should be: resp = { 1:A, 2:B, 3:C }[args[0] - 1]

Because it's not zero-indexed.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
RandomResponder = [A, B, C]
RandomResponder[0].doSomething()   # returns A.doSomething()
RandomResponder[1].doSomething()   # returns B.doSomething()
RandomResponder[2].doSomething()   # returns C.doSomething()
# etc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify `args` (without the asterisk), it's just a List of values (strings).  Similarly, `kwargs` is a Dict of matching keys (strings) to values (strings).

[This](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/) is one of the first results I found after Googling [args kwargs](http://www.google.com/search?q=args+kwargs).

Edit: I actually don't know quite what you're looking for, so this is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this?

```
from responders import A, B, C

class RandomResponder(object)

    def pickAResponder( self, someName ):
        """Use a simple mapping."""
        return  { 'nameA': A, 'nameB': B, 'nameC': C }[someName]

    def __init__(self, *args, *kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        """pick a responder based on the args[0]"""
        r = self.pickAResponder(self.args[0])
        responder = r(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        return responder.__getattr__(name)
```

Your responder classes (A, B, C) are just objects.  You can manipulate a class using mappings, lists, if-statements, whatever Python coding you want in the `pickAResponder` method.

Comment: Close, but I don't want the use the args from the __init__, I want to use the args that the attribute is called with.